# Expected value and variance of n iid Normal Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, variance

I'm trying to calculate the expected value and variance of the product of n (a known integer) iid Normal Random variables with no luck!

$X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^2), $

$Z = \prod_{i=1}^n  X_i $

Since $X_i$ are independent, I used the product rule and wrote

$ E[Y] = E[X_1] \times ... \times E[X_n] = \mu \times ... \times \mu  = \mu^n $

For Variance, I used the definition:

$
Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2 = E[X_1^2 \times ... \times X_n^2] - (E[X_1 \times ... \times X_n])^2
$

Calculating the value for $(E[X_1 \times ... \times X_n])^2$ is easy; $\mu^{2n}$

I can't get the value for $E[Y^2]$. I used the definition of expected value and get to an integral that is diverging.

$E[Y^2] = E[X_1^2 \times ... \times X_n^2] = \idotsint_{-\infty}^\infty c_1x_1^2e^{1/2({x_1-\mu}/\sigma)^2}...c_nx_n^2e^{1/2({x_n-\mu}/\sigma)^2} d_{x_1}...d_{x_n} 
$
and $c_i$ is the coefficient for PDF of the normal distribution. I can take the $c_i$ out, so it would be this integral:

$
c_1...c_n\idotsint_{-\infty}^\infty x_1^2e^{1/2({x_1-\mu}/\sigma)^2} ...x_n^2e^{1/2({x_n-\mu}/\sigma)^2} d_{x_1}...d_{x_n}
$

Comment: If the $X_i$ are iid the $X^2_i$ are as well.

Comment: Note that the distribution of the product is not normally distributed, and the shape changes not only with $n$ but also with $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments $X_i^2$ are independent if $X_i$ are

$E(X_1^2\dots X_n^2 )=\prod _{i =1}^n E(X_1^2)= \prod _{i =1}^n \left (Var (X_1)+( EX_1)^2\right)=(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^n$

Hence the overall variance is $$(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^n-\mu^{2n}$$